# laravel new command with older version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to create new Laravel project using below commands:

```
laravel new --5.2 blog

laravel new blog --5.2
```

Gives me following error:

```
Crafting application...

  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
  Client error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest-52.zip` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)

new [--dev] [--5.2] [--] [<name>]
```

I am running the command under XAMPP 5.6.28 > Terminal

PHP version: 5.6.28

Composer version: 1.3.2

Laravel Installer version: 1.3.3

Comment: try using composer.
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"`

Comment: It is working fine. But I just need to understand what's wrong with laravel new utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug at Laravel's side:

```
https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L125
```

Trying to download in the browser:

http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest-52.zip

results in a 404.

Comment: How have they still not fixed it in 2021?