# Installing Laravel 5.2 via Laravel Installer gives me this error. How can I resolve it?

Tags: laravel

```
c:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new --5.2 MyNewProj

Crafting application...
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
Client error: 'GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest-52.zip' resulted in a '404 Not Found' response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)

new [--dev] [--5.2] [--] [<name>]
```

While executing the laravel installer command I get this error. 
I want to install laravel using the **installer only**.
So how can I **resolve** this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug at laravel side, see here Not found error:
http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest-52.zip

See this post, it is a duplicate of this post:
[laravel new command with older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149219/laravel-new-command-with-older-version)